# SQL Server error "Conversion failed" while using CAST or CONVERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am quite new in sql server. I am trying to run this following query:

```
SELECT AVG( jl.[Stock Weight] ) 
    FROM [Settlement Line] jl 
    WHERE jl.[Vendor No_] = 8516 
    AND ( jl.[Slaughter Date] BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' ) 
    AND ( CAST( jl.[Item No_] AS INT ) BETWEEN 17000 AND 17099 )
```

As a result, I get this error:

> OperationalError: (245, "Conversion failed when converting the varchar
>   value 'PRISGAR.'

I cannot figure this out. I can't also figure out what `PRISGAR` is. I have tried with `CONVERT`also, got same error. The field `[Item No_]`is a  `varchar(20)`which I am trying to convert into `INT` and check between two numbers.

Comment: Could you provide the schema of your tables so we can see what types the fields are please? It's just a type error.

Comment: One row has `PRISGAR` as the value in `[Item No_]` field. That cannot be converted to `INT`

Comment: Side note: [you don't want to use `BETWEEN` for date/time types on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (or really, much of anywhere else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear from the error whether the error is for `[Vendor No_]` or `[Item No_]` or `jl.[Stock Weight]`.  SQL is strongly typed, but does type conversions.  You should try to do the comparisons using the same type and not to store numbers as strings.

If the problem is the average, then you can use a `case`.  Something like:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(jl.[Stock Weight]) = 1
                THEN CAST(jl.[Stock Weight] as FLOAT)
           END)
```

For the comparison logic, this suggests using the same type as the column for the constant:

```
j1.[Vendor No_] = '8516'
```

The `[Item No_]` is a bit more troublesome.  It is tempting to write:

```
jl.[Item No_] BETWEEN '17000' AND '17099'
```

However, this would match '170019991234545', because the comparisons would be done as strings, not numbers.  Another method is:

```
(jl.[Item No_] BETWEEN '17000' AND '17099' AND LEN(jl.[Item No_]) = 5)
```

However, this would match '1702A'.  Yet another can use `LIKE` to ensure the values are all digits:

```
(jl.[Item No_] BETWEEN '17000' AND '17099' AND
 jl.[Item No_] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
)
```

And this can be simplified to:

```
(jl.[Item No_] LIKE '170[0-9][0-9]')
```

Comment: Was helpful for what I was trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT AVG(jl.[Stock Weight]) 
FROM dbo.[Settlement Line] jl 
WHERE jl.[Vendor No_] = 8516
    AND jl.[Slaughter Date] BETWEEN '20151101' AND '20151130'
    AND jl.[Item No_] BETWEEN '17000' AND '17099'
```

Answer (score 0):

Column jl.[Item No_]  contains string as somewhere. Check all rows and remove string from that Column then use above query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use case expression (this may err for some special strings, like '.', you can add some additional checks):

```
case 
    when isnumeric(jl.[Item No_]) = 1 
    then CAST( jl.[Item No_] AS INT ) 
    else 0 
end BETWEEN 17000 AND 17099
```